# When I use postman and click on send I get an error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, postman, rest

I get the following error when I click send in postman.  I even used async await instead of promise, but it still did not solve the issue.

```
(node:4120) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseServerSelectionError: 
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\Users\negin\Desktop\restAPI\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:800:32)
    at C:\Users\negin\Desktop\restAPI\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:341:10
    at C:\Users\negin\Desktop\restAPI\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:31:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\negin\Desktop\restAPI\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:30:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\negin\Desktop\restAPI\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:340:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\negin\Desktop\restAPI\app.js:6:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
(node:4120) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). 
To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:4120) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. 

In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: ensure you but the database link in the server and you use it

Comment: I checked the URL in my entry point and it was wrong.now it works